# Efficiency formula code in Pattern matching

Tags: java, performance, pattern-matching

I need a formula that will determine the efficiency of the system in pattern matching
using time and the number of comparison factors.

Is there any formula that would produce numeric output using these factors?

Comment: Could you give an example of a program that does this?

Comment: You would have to look at the compiled regex and apply O(n) analysis to each individual operation, where `n` would be different at each point depending on the input.  In other words, there's probably no "formula" other than benchmarking.

Comment: Good luck.  This will depend extremely heavily on your regex engine.

Comment: I would like to determine the efficiency of the pattern matching algorithm that is used. where the system observes the time and the number of comparisons that the process spent to finish the task. The input would also be different at each point..

Answer (score 0):

If you asking if there is a general formula that characterizes the performance of a regular expression pattern matcher for a given pattern and a given input, then the answer is that there is no such formula.  The problem is far too complicated to be reduced to a formula.

And when you add in the fact that different pattern matching algorithms work in different ways, the problem gets even more complicated.